# iterm2: How to select emoji, or do automatic text replacement, or use macOS "Symbol and text substitution"?

Tags: macos, vim, emoji, iterm2

I want to be able to easily insert emoji into an iTerm2 terminal (in `vim`).  Either of the following solutions would be nice:

1. Have a quick access emoji selector in iTerm2 or vim (e.g., like Slack and Discord `:smile:` to get )
2. Use the macOS built-in ["Symbol and text substitution" text replacements](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/replace-text-punctuation-documents-mac-mh35735/10.14/mac/10.14) (System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > (Replace | With)).  (These substitutions don't happen in iTerm2)

The following does work, but is slower / less preferable than the above desired solutions:
a. Open the [macOS Character Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-emoji-and-symbols-on-mac-mchlp1560/10.14/mac/10.14) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>)
b. Select `emoji`
c. Double-click on an emoji to insert it

iTerm2 version:  `3.4.0beta10`
macOS version: `macOS Mojave 10.14.6`

Reference: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/5386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Snippets**: iTerm2 has a `Snippets` functionality where you can add each emoji as a separate snippet, and then select the snippet to paste it:

To add/edit snippets:

```
Preferences > Shortcuts > Snippets
```

To view Snippets in the toolbelt:

```
(Menu bar) > Toolbelt > Snippets
```

To open the toolbelt:

```
(Menu bar) > Toolbelt > Show Toolbelt
(keyboard shortcut: shift + cmd + B)
```

To make the toolbelt always open in new windows:

```
Preferences > Profiles > Window Settings for New Windows > Open toolbelt
```

---

If using `vim`, consider creating vim abbreviations for emoji.  e.g., given the following vim abbreviation, after you type `_smile` in vim insert mode, vim will replace `_smile` with :

`:iabbrev _smile` 
`:help abbreviations`